# No GUI, No internet connection, please help 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, gui, internet-connection, wireless-access-point

I am new to Ubuntu and I tried to install ubuntu server 12.04 on my laptop. now my problem is - I am unable to connect to the internet (I have wifi ONLY connection). ubuntu didn't recognize my built-in wifi on my Toshiba Satellite L505. There is no GUI. I have Terminal only, I tried Sudo apt-get update but i am getting errer msg because of no connection.
1. I need to know if there is any possible way that i can download and install driver for my wifi.
2. what other option do i have to be able to update ubuntu.

Thanks
KB

Comment: Server has no GUI by default. You can use `iwconfig` to connect to wifi. But if you are new to Ubuntu and want to try it out, I suggest you install the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server has no GUI by default.

Your two other questions are:

1. Can I download and install the driver for my wifi network card?
2. Is there another way (outside of wifi )to update Ubuntu?

I also recently installed the server version of 12.04. I think the answer to these two questions are:

1. You need to tell us what wifi network card your Toshiba has. The most important thing is the chipset. But the problem here is that even if there was a wifi card driver that you could download, you're using wifi. So the answer would be no. I suggest trying a wired ethernet connection.
2. The answer is yes. Use wireless ethernet. Honestly, @Mahesh's suggestion is the best for you. You can always install those server components later.